# Active-admin error message is not displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have added a customized controller in my active-admin user.rb file. While am updating an user details from active-admin it will call update method inside the customized controller. The actual problem which i facing is when i include flash message inside the method it is not displaying.

```
controller do
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.update(expert_params)
    redirect_to temanage_user_path(@user), :notice => "attempting to set notice via redirect_to"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
controller do
  def update
    update! do |success, failure|
      success.html do
        redirect_to temanage_user_path(@user), notice: 'Updated! Redirecting.'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

P.S. You should find @user is already set for you.

Comment: It is not working for me Mr. @Piers. Is there any other solution to resolve the issue or it is happening bcz of any design overriding?